# BC50319 error using OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter.Fill

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio

I get the error [BC50319](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30519) on 'da.Fill(DataTableWorkstation)' which is part of this segment:

```
        Using da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(oleExcelCommand)
            DataTableWorkstation = New System.Data.DataTable
            da.Fill(DataTableWorkstation)
        End Using
```

In that line I am opening a .xlsx-file containing data (strings, numbers and dates) and save this data to a `DataTable`.
As "solution" Microsoft tells me to change to `Option Strict Off` which I do want to avoid. Is there a another solution for this?

Comment: What is the data type of `DataTableWorkstation`?

Comment: @user18387401: I initialized the variable as like `Dim DataTableWorkstation As DataTable`. After your comment, I found my mistake. I have to initialize the variable: `Dim DataTableWorkstation As System.Data.DataTable` and the error is gone. Thanks for your help! @Jimi: copied the wrong error. Fixed now :)

Comment: That solution seems to suggest that you have declared your own type named `DataTable` somewhere else and the declaration was being interpreted as that type. The better solution would be to not use that name for your own type if possible and avoid the name clash with commonly-used existing types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for the problem is, that I need to be explicit when initializing variables. I had to change the initialization of my variable from this:

```
Dim DataTableWorkstation As DataTable
```

to this:

```
Dim DataTableWorkstation As System.Data.DataTable
```

and the error is gone.

Comment: No, you don't need to, unless you messed up a class declaration, naming it `DataTable`, for some reason.